# Joomla Form Creation & PDF Conversion

Tags: forms, pdf, joomla

I want to convert my client registration form online.I want to have

1. PHP Form with validation
2. Form data should be inserted in database
3. After form submission,end user should be able to download form as pdf.
4. I am having pdf file format ready with me,form data should be added at specific position in pdf
5. Backoffice should be able to view all forms filled & able to create csv file for same.

Can i achieve my requirement using Joomla?
I am new to joomla.

Comment: You might have to look into creating you're own components or get someone to develop it for you, however there are lots of form components on the Joomla Extensions Directory, some of which I am certain will cater for requirements 1, 2, and 3. Some may even cater for 4 and 5 so best have a look on the Joomla Extensions Directory. Note that the extension you find may be commercial

Comment: Thanks...I am installing Joomla now.But i am stuck at configuration page only.I added main configuration & then click on next button.But i am getting symbol of processing,i am not redirected to database setting page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this link: http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html

RSForm Pro has the feature to download the form submission in PDF form. You will have to specify the layout of the PDF in the extension itself.